# Proving that $S^1 \vee S^1$'s covering space is universal

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

In Hatcher, they give the following example of a simply connected covering space of $S^1 \vee S^1$ [image]. I am having trouble convincing myself that it is simply connected. I suspect it is contractible. However, I am getting lost with the infinity of of steps it would take to contract it.

Might anyone have any hints? Thank you in advance,

Raphaël Fua

Comment: Use the fact that the image of a loop must be compact.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I am afraid I still do not get it. The continuous image of a compact set is compact. So I agree with your comment. But I do not see how to use it. If we suppose for a contradiction that there were two non homotopic loops with the same basepoint, why would the image of one of these loops not be compact?

Comment: If you know that finite trees are contractible, then as per Randall's answer, you can prove the desired result about covering spaces without giving an explicit proof that the whole space is contractible. Alternatively, you can see that any tree $T$ with root $r$ that can be embedded into a bounded metric space is contractible by using a homotopy that maps $(x, t) \in T \times [0, 1]$ to the unique point on the path from $r$ to $x$ that has length $td(r, x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry about showing that the cover is contractible:  just show that every loop is homotopic to the constant loop.

For that, let $E$ be the supposed universal cover in your post and let $\alpha$ be a loop in $E$.  Since the image of $\alpha$ must be compact, its image must live in a finite sub-tree $T$ of $E$.  The point is that $\alpha$ can't be wild and run off to all these strange infinite corners:  it's contained in a finite sub-tree.  Now, Hatcher proves that finite trees are contractible, so use that to give a homotopy of $\alpha$ down to the constant map.  That same homotopy in $T$ is a homotopy within $E$ by inclusions, so you're done.